# Esp8266 cannot connect to MQTT network with WiFiClientSecure setCaCert?

Tags: mqtt, esp8266, mosquitto, nodemcu, hivemq

I'm working on an IoT project. I use Hivemq as an mqqt service. He's connected to Mosquitto on the server. I could normally connect to MQTT without certification locally. When he switched to Globale, that is, when he used hivemq, mosquitto asked for a TLS certificate. Hivemq provides that. when we communicate through the computer, there are no certificate problems. I can communicate via mosquitto. When I tried this process through ESP8266 nodeMCU, I could not connect to server with the certificate and it gets the following error code. (Attempting MQTT connection...failed, rc=-2 try again in 5 seconds
) (Unable to connect).The code is below. I couldn't find a sample on the internet. net.I may be encoding the setCACert function missing or incorrectly. I'd appreciate it if you could help me. For days I work.

```
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
#include <PubSubClient.h>
#include <WiFiClientSecure.h>


const char* ssid     = "samsung";     // your network SSID (name of wifi network)
const char* password = "123456789"; // your network password
const char* mqttUser = "Halil";
const char* mqttPassword = "Halil.123";

const char*  mqtt_server  = "46.137.47.218";  // Server URL
const char* test_root_ca= \
 "-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----\n" \
 "MIIDSjCCAjKgAwIBAgIQRK+wgNajJ7qJMDmGLvhAazANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQUFADA/\n" \
 "MSQwIgYDVQQKExtEaWdpdGFsIFNpZ25hdHVyZSBUcnVzdCBDby4xFzAVBgNVBAMT\n" \
 "DkRTVCBSb290IENBIFgzMB4XDTAwMDkzMDIxMTIxOVoXDTIxMDkzMDE0MDExNVow\n" \
 "PzEkMCIGA1UEChMbRGlnaXRhbCBTaWduYXR1cmUgVHJ1c3QgQ28uMRcwFQYDVQQD\n" \
 "Ew5EU1QgUm9vdCBDQSBYMzCCASIwDQYJKoZIhvcNAQEBBQADggEPADCCAQoCggEB\n" \
 "AN+v6ZdQCINXtMxiZfaQguzH0yxrMMpb7NnDfcdAwRgUi+DoM3ZJKuM/IUmTrE4O\n" \
 "rz5Iy2Xu/NMhD2XSKtkyj4zl93ewEnu1lcCJo6m67XMuegwGMoOifooUMM0RoOEq\n" \
 "OLl5CjH9UL2AZd+3UWODyOKIYepLYYHsUmu5ouJLGiifSKOeDNoJjj4XLh7dIN9b\n" \
 "xiqKqy69cK3FCxolkHRyxXtqqzTWMIn/5WgTe1QLyNau7Fqckh49ZLOMxt+/yUFw\n" \
 "7BZy1SbsOFU5Q9D8/RhcQPGX69Wam40dutolucbY38EVAjqr2m7xPi71XAicPNaD\n" \
 "aeQQmxkqtilX4+U9m5/wAl0CAwEAAaNCMEAwDwYDVR0TAQH/BAUwAwEB/zAOBgNV\n" \
 "HQ8BAf8EBAMCAQYwHQYDVR0OBBYEFMSnsaR7LHH62+FLkHX/xBVghYkQMA0GCSqG\n" \
 "SIb3DQEBBQUAA4IBAQCjGiybFwBcqR7uKGY3Or+Dxz9LwwmglSBd49lZRNI+DT69\n" \
 "ikugdB/OEIKcdBodfpga3csTS7MgROSR6cz8faXbauX+5v3gTt23ADq1cEmv8uXr\n" \
 "AvHRAosZy5Q6XkjEGB5YGV8eAlrwDPGxrancWYaLbumR9YbK+rlmM6pZW87ipxZz\n" \
 "R8srzJmwN0jP41ZL9c8PDHIyh8bwRLtTcm1D9SZImlJnt1ir/md2cXjbDaJWFBM5\n" \
 "JDGFoqgCWjBH4d1QB7wCCZAA62RjYJsWvIjJEubSfZGL+T0yjWW06XyxV3bqxbYo\n" \
 "Ob8VZRzI9neWagqNdwvYkQsEjgfbKbYK7p2CNTUQ\n"\
 "-----END CERTIFICATE-----\n";

WiFiClientSecure net;
 
WiFiClient espClient;
PubSubClient client(espClient);
unsigned long lastMsg = 0;
#define MSG_BUFFER_SIZE (50)
char msg[MSG_BUFFER_SIZE];
int value = 0;

void setup_wifi() {

  delay(10);
  // We start by connecting to a WiFi network
  Serial.println();
  Serial.print("Connecting to ");
  Serial.println(ssid);

  WiFi.begin(ssid, password);

  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
    delay(500);
    Serial.print("..");
  }

  randomSeed(micros());

  Serial.println("");
  Serial.println("WiFi connected");
  Serial.println("IP address: ");
  Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());
}

void callback(char* topic, byte* payload, unsigned int length) {
  Serial.print("Message arrived [");
  Serial.print(topic);
  Serial.print("] ");
  for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    Serial.print((char)payload[i]);
  }
  Serial.println();

  // Switch on the LED if an 1 was received as first character
  if ((char)payload[0] == '1') {
    digitalWrite(BUILTIN_LED, LOW);   // Turn the LED on (Note that LOW is the voltage level
    // but actually the LED is on; this is because
    // it is active low on the ESP-01)
  } else {
    digitalWrite(BUILTIN_LED, HIGH);  // Turn the LED off by making the voltage HIGH
  }
}

void reconnect() {
  // Loop until we're reconnected
  while (!client.connected()) {
    Serial.print("Attempting MQTT connection...");
    // Create a random client ID
    String clientId = "ESP8266Client-";
    clientId += String(random(0xffff), HEX);
    if (client.connect(clientId.c_str(), mqttUser, mqttPassword)) {
      Serial.println("connected");
      client.subscribe("CoreElectronics/test");
    } else {
      Serial.print("failed, rc=");
      Serial.print(client.state());
      Serial.println(" try again in 5 seconds");
      // Wait 5 seconds before retrying
      delay(5000);
    }
  }
}

void setup() {
  pinMode(BUILTIN_LED, OUTPUT);
  Serial.begin(115200);
  setup_wifi();
   
  client.setServer(mqtt_server, 8883);
 net.setCACert((const uint8_t*)test_root_ca,sizeof(test_root_ca)-1);
  client.setCallback(callback);
}

void loop() {

  if (!client.connected()) {
    reconnect();
  }
  client.loop();
}
```

Comment: You should use the `WiFiClientSecure` client to initialize the `PubSubClient`, so: `PubSubClient client(net)`. Does it work if you change that?

Comment: I tried many times, but it didn't work out. I think my key or code MQTT server connection sequence is wrong?

Comment: In addition, it could be that you are not passing the CA certificate in the right format, check comments #9 and #11 here [link](https://forum.arduino.cc/t/mqtt-and-tls/665171/8). In anycase, I would first confirm that you can establish a TLS connection from a client on your laptop (e.g. mosquitto-client, mqq-spy). To make sure that the problem is not on the server side or on the certificate.